# Conditionally applying alpha parameter for some values in geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

I am using `geom_tile` to create a heatmap. I want to customize the heatmap by highlighting cells that meet a certain criteria. Specifically, I want any cell with a value less than 10 to be set to a lower transparency. Everything above 10 should be `alpha=1`.  I've tried to apply this condition with `alpha=ifelse(spinrate >= 10, 1, 0.5)`, but it seems `alpha` is not interpreted as I would expect it to be.

Reproducible Example:

```
spinrates <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/spinrates.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(aes(x=velocity, y=spinrate, fill=swing_miss, label=swing_miss, alpha=ifelse(swing_miss >= 10, 1, .3)), data=spinrates) +
 geom_tile(show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(size=2.25, show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn", direction = 1)
```

[image: geom_tile]

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(aes(x=velocity, y=spinrate, fill=swing_miss, label=swing_miss, alpha = swing_miss), 
       data=spinrates) +
  geom_tile(show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(size=2.25, show.legend = F) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn", direction = 1)+
  scale_alpha_continuous(ifelse(spinrates$swing_miss>=10, 1,0.5))
```

Comment: I think your code is correct, values>10 has apha 1, and rest 0.5. I just posted another option you can play with alpha, but not surew whether that is what you wanna achieve

Comment: Thanks for response.  However, when I change the lower value for alpha, the chart doesn't actually update like I would expect it to.  So if you change `ifelse(spinrates$swing_miss>=10, 1,0.5)` to `ifelse(spinrates$swing_miss>=10, 1,0.1)`, I would except more transparency in the cells that meet that condition, but the transparency remains the same as before.